# allow html but protect from mysqli injection

Tags: php, html, mysqli, code-injection

i am trying to do this for past days , i tried many functions such as

> **strip_tags , mysqli_real_escape_string , ..etc**

```
// Prevent MySQL Injection Attacks
function cleanQuery($connector,$string){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())  // prevents duplicate backslashes
        $string = stripslashes($string);
    return mysqli_escape_string($connector,$string);
}
```

but none gave me the result i want .

what i want is to enter an article text , allow html editing but prevent from mysqli injection ... can anyone helpout ?

as an example :
i have this :

```
$data     = $_POST['data'];


echo "<form method='POST' action='index.php?do=check'>
<textarea rows='10' name='data' cols='50'>$data</textarea>
<input type='submit' value='send' name='B1'>
</form>
  ";



mysqli_query($conn,"insert into table(field)values('$data')");
```

value of data is :

```
<p align="center"><b><font size="6">test</font></b></p>
<table border='1' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;what's your name ?</td>
        <td>&nbsp;my name is `Jhone`</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**an html input**

so how can i insert that into database with no issues ?

Comment: myslqi prepared statements will give you all the necessary protection

Comment: use prepared statements

Comment: You want to use prepared statements.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: What makes you think that code won't protect you from SQL Injection? (It's suboptimal (prepared statements are a better approach), weirdly does input fixing at the same time as output preparation, but I don't see anything that would make it fail).

Comment: `DEFINE` (expected) results.

Comment: sorry but i didnot get how that will help in securing input ?

Comment: You shouldn't secure input, but use the correct escaping/encoding function on output, depending on the context. As others said, use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: allowing html has nothing to do with SQL protection. Are you sure you don't mean allow html and avoid XSS?

Comment: i want to allow html , but `':; .. those makes issues while inserting in db ..that's all ..

Comment: Here is an example on how `mysqli_real_escape_string` is used `$message=mysqli_real_escape_string($connector, $_POST['message']);`, `IF` that is what you're asking, which for the moment, is unclear. @Hussein

Comment: all i want is securing an input value before adding to database , not changing everything around :) ,

Comment: But you're already doing that. As Quentin said, it's suboptimal, but it will work if you use that function on variables you want to insert into a database.

Comment: question edited for more explanation of my issue .. please recheck ..

Comment: Just read the following, which is where many refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php as well as https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10 that's the best advice I can give you. You just need to read and understand how things work. Good luck.

Comment: Apart from @Fred-ii-'s comment, you're not using your function before feeding your variable into your database. But you should really have a look at prepared statements.

Comment: issue solved through prepare : http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php , too time to work with as i want but it works the trick .. thank all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue solved through **[prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)**  as you guys said ,
 took time to work with as i want but it works the trick .. thank all

for selecting and executing :

```
$stmt = $connector->prepare('select * from TABLENAME where FIELD1 = ? and FIELD2 = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $FIELD1_VALUE,$FIELD2_VALUE);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}

$stmt->close();
```

IN line 1 : change where you want to insert the value with **?**
IN lne 2 : for each **?** , put s and add value as shown above.

and for Inserting :

```
$stmt = $connector->prepare('insert into TABLE(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3)values(?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sss',  $FIELD1_VALUE,$FIELD2_VALUE,$FIELD3_VALUE);

if ($stmt->execute()){
echo "data added ";

}else{

echo "Error adding data ".$stmt->error ;
}

$stmt->close();
```

same rule applies

Hope that helps!
Regards,

Comment: Could you please share your improved code in your answer, so that others can learn from it?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel , ans. updated.

Answer (score -1):

MySQLi... try this code:

```
// Prevent MySQL Injection Attacks
function cleanQuery($connector,$string){
    return $connector->real_escape_string($string);
}
```

If you're using mysqli this code will work out perfectly for you.

Comment: What is `addslashesh`? You meant `addslashes` ;-)

Comment: Oh God, why! Why addslashes() after real_escape_String??

Comment: No, no, no, don't use `addslashes`! Apart from that, the code is the same as that of the OP.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Little detail: he's doing it *before* `real_escape_string`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel you're right, I wrote it in haste :), but that's what I meant too

Comment: with all these sugestions , i think i'm confused .. :/

Comment: Fixed the addslashes mistake, also it'll work perfectly fine. Tested.

Comment: @xMoltenX Are you sure? Did you try to insert an item with a single quote in it? Than you'll end up with a backslash in your database. `addslashes` should *never* be used.

Comment: @Hussein What's confusing you? Can you explain, preferably by editing your question?

Comment: Removed addslashes...I guess it's killing everything for some people.

Comment: question edited for more explanation of my issue .. please recheck it ..